# Is it possible to find out *who* created a short Google URL (like goo.gl/something)?

Tags: url-shortening, goo.gl

I was wondering: is it possible for other people to find out who created a short `goo.gl` URL (that I created using my own Google account)? That is, can they trace it back to my Google account?

Answer (score 19):

From [Google's site](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190768):

> The Google URL Shortener provides the following safeguards to address user privacy concerns:
>
> - The goo.gl short URLs do not publicly reveal the identity of the user who created that URL mapping.
> - The goo.gl short URL history for a user is accessible only when signed in using that Google Account.
> - The analytics for all goo.gl short URLs are displayed in aggregate.

So, only Google knows who created goo.gl short links.